# TYPO3 + Fluid: How to use f:translate as an argument for a partial?

Tags: typo3, partial, fluid

I've a Fluid template with a partial. To fetch a localized string I'm using `<f:translate key="myKey" />`.

I wonder how to use `f:translate` as an argument for my partial.

According to the [documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/other/typo3/view-helper-reference/9.5/en-us/typo3/fluid/latest/Translate.html) there is a inline-notation: `{f:translate(key: 'someKey', extensionName)}` but this doesn't seem to work in my case and causes an error:

```
<f:render partial="Mail/MailHeader" arguments="{subject:{f:translate(key: 'myKey')}}" />
```

Error message:

> Wed, 25 Nov 2020 10:25:10 +0100 [CRITICAL] request="8f19ae8768390"
> component="In2code.Powermail.Controller.FormController": Mail could
> not be sent - ["The argument "arguments" was registered with type
> "array", but is of type "string" in view helper
> "TYPO3\CMS\Fluid\ViewHelpers\RenderViewHelper"."]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're missing the quotes around the subject variable

```
<f:render partial="Mail/MailHeader" arguments="{subject:'{f:translate(key: \'myKey\')}'}" />
```